# How can I edit the fields of a heading/outline level in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have a document in Word organized with multi-level outlines, using the default headings styles.

When I create a Table of Contents, it creates an hyperlink to those headings/outlines, but it usually refers to a field named _TOC10001237, for example. Each heading/outline level receives its name automatically, but I would like to change some of the names of these references from "_TOC10001237" to "_TOCtheNameIwant".

Toggling the fields on/off doesn't give me access to change that. How can I do it?